# Moving text files with the same name "meeting_saved_chat.txt" to parent folder

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've been having trouble with this for about a month with no progress, please help.
I have a Parent folder named Zoomproj  in this folder is my python script and another folder named saved-meetings-backup (*not sure if this is relevant) which is a copy of another folder in a different directory named saved_meeting. In saved-meetings-backup, I have about 12 folders they all have similar names but are differentiated by the date, for example one folder is named "2021-05-06 12.50.38 Daniel Zoom Meeting 97242325090", and another is named "2021-05-12 11.17.12 Daniel Zoom Meeting 97242325090" inside all these folders there is a just a single file named "meeting_saved_chat.txt". I've tried using shutil and glob and os.path.join to no avail, heres my original code that didn't work:

```
targ = r"Users/myname/projects/ZoomProj" + "//"
src = r"/Users/myname/projects/ZoomProj/saved-meeting-backup" + "//"
count = 0

for path, dirs, file in os.path.walk(src):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith('.txt'):
            count += 1
            nfname =  os.path.splitext(file)[0] + "_" str(count) + os.path.splitext(file)[1]
            shutil.copy(nfname, targ)
```

I get an Error, No Such file or directory.  I've narrowed down the problem and it seems like python doesn't regonize these as files so I tried this

```
target_folder = r"/Users/myname/projects/ZoomProj" + "//"
src_folder = r"/Users/myname/projects/ZoomProj/saved-meeting-backup" + "//"
count = 0 

for path, dirs, file in os.path.walk(src_folder):
    if files:
        for file in files:
            if os.path.isfile(file):
                print(True)
            else:
                print(False)
```

this prints false for all the text files, and I'm not sure why. I know, I should read the docs but i've tried that. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why are you appending `//` to the pathnames?

Comment: You should start the pathname with `/` to make it absolute.

Comment: `targ = r"/Users/myname/projects/ZoomProj"`

Comment: I don't understand what `nfname` is supposed to be. The first argument to `shutil.copy()` should be the name of the file you want to copy. Why are you inserting `count` into the filename? That file doesn't exist. Is that the name of the destination file you want to create?

Answer (score 0):

You're putting `count` into the source file when copying. It should be in the destination file.

Get the basename of `file`, split it into the name and extension, insert the count there, and join that to the target directory.

```
targ = r"/Users/myname/projects/ZoomProj"
src = r"/Users/myname/projects/ZoomProj/saved-meeting-backup"

for count, file in enumerate(glob.glob(os.path.join(src, "*.txt")), 1):
    base = os.path.split(file)[1]
    (name, ext) = os.path.splitext(base)
    nfname =  f"{name}_{count}{ext}"
    shutil.copy(file, os.path.join(targ, nfname))
```